# A clever trick to prevent Task<IDisposable> from being used in C# using clause without await

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a number of methods that currently return an awaitable `Task<IDisposable>`.

Is there a way to change the return type so that the following would become a compile-time error?

```
using (GetExclusiveLockAsync())
{
    ...
}
```

The idea is to get the compiler to remind me that I should have written it like this:

```
using (await GetExclusiveLockAsync())
{
    ...
}
```

As it is, GetExclusiveLockAsync returns `Task<IDisposable>` which also implements IDisposable (via base Task class). Both snippets compile, but one of them is wrong. I DON'T want to dispose of the task, only its result!

Is there a clever trick to make the first one a compile-time error?

**UPDATE**: Based on comments so far it seems that the pattern demonstrated was confusing. I've now changed the name of the method from original `GetAsync` to `GetExclusiveLockAsync` to better illustrate the actual intended use. It's basically an async synchronization lock, which is the main reason why I don't need to declare the variable in the `using` line nor consume it inside the following block. It only serves to protect the block of code it surrounds from parallel effects.

Comment: Parse your source and check for those lines specific. There's no real compile time in C# and it sucks that there isn't for situations like this.

Comment: Sounds like something you could write a Roslyn analyzer for.

Comment: If the whole purpose is to return something that must be disposed of immediately, why are you returning anything at all, why aren't you simply disposing of this objects on the inside and return just a `Task`?

Comment: @Lasse: I'm hoping the three dots in the using block would imply I'm doing something useful there before letting the awaited IDisposable be disposed. :) While I have a couple of different scenarios, two of them are basically async locks. As in, I GetAsync() a lock handle, do something while holding it, then dispose (release) the lock. Is this clearer?

Comment: @Bauss & Damien: That's not what I'd consider a clever trick. :) FWIW, I seem to recall a code snippet from one of the Stephen's (Cleary or Toub, I do not remember which one) that did something like this using a custom awaiter that wasn't disposable. I can't find it, though...

Comment: Yes, you can "easily" wrap up the result in something with a `GetAwaiter`, which allows it to be awaited, but not disposed. You will need to expose a public method that calls an internal method that has the real async/await pattern, wrapping up the task on its way out of your class into your new custom type. This because the C# compiler will not allow you to write async/await type of code inside a method that does not return Task.

Comment: I personally find this a little odd, if the method is `GetAsync` and it returns an `IDisposable`, typically you'd consume the instance returned from the get invocation within the `using` block. `using (var foo = await GetAsync()) { ... }`.

Comment: @David: Sure. But not if it's a lock handle or similar, which is intended exclusively for synchronization with other similar blocks of code running in parallel. Would GetExclusiveLockAsync() be a clearer name?

Comment: @aoven absolutely...that is a much better name. It says what it is actually doing!

Comment: David: Thanks. I've updated my question in hope it's now less confusing. To be fair, the actual line in my code is: using (await UnitOfWork.AllocateAsync()). It's not a direct async lock request, but under the hood, it does take one. I just didn't wish to pollute my question with needless details. I believe it can be generalized to any case of Task<IDisposable>.

Comment: @David: Because it's not that simple, for one. You're getting too attached to example from my question, I'm afraid. As I've explained, it's not about taking a lock in all cases I'm trying to address. And even when it is, the lock is not semaphore-like, at all! It's more of an async reader-writer lock with a lot of additional features you can't possibly hope to find in a generic lock implementation. Not trying to be secretive here, but the details are just too complicated and not at all relevant to this question. Almost any method returning Task<IDisposable> can benefit from solution. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a clever trick to make the first one a compile-time error?

Yes, you can change the return type to be something else.

I use this approach in my `AsyncEx` library, using the [`AwaitableDisposable<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AwaitableDisposable.cs). In short:

```
public struct AwaitableDisposable<T> where T : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Task<T> _task;
    public AwaitableDisposable(Task<T> task) { _task = task; }

    public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() => _task.GetAwaiter();
    public ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T> ConfigureAwait(bool continueOnCapturedContext) =>
        _task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);

    public Task<T> AsTask() => _task;
    public static implicit operator Task<T>(AwaitableDisposable<T> source) =>
        source.AsTask();
}
```

You can return `AwaitableDisposable<T>` from your `GetExclusiveLockAsync` instead of a regular `Task<T>`. It's a `struct` for minimal overhead.

The implicit conversion and `GetAwaiter`/`ConfigureAwait` methods allow "tasklike" usage:

```
// All of these work.
IDisposable key = await GetExclusiveLockAsync();
IDisposable key = await GetExclusiveLockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
Task<TDisposable> lockTask = GetExclusiveLockAsync();
using (await GetExclusiveLockAsync()) { }
```

There are some situations where the implicit conversion isn't sufficient, e.g., some `Task.WhenAll` uses. For these cases, the user can call `AsTask`:

```
// Not pretty, but doable.
await Task.WhenAll(x.GetExclusiveLockAsync().AsTask(),
    y.GetExclusiveLockAsync().AsTask());
```

And, of course, the entire purpose of `AwaitableDisposable<T>` is that it is *not* disposable, so this fails at compile-time:

```
using (GetExclusiveLockAsync()) { }
```